# insert json object with array inside into mysql table using node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, aws-lambda, node-mysql

I am using aws as my backend and i have few aws lambda functions (written in node JS) that are used to insert incoming json data to amazon RDS(mysql) DB. Below is my node js code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool = mysql.createPool({.../});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let inserts = [event.unitID, event.timestamp, event.frequency];
  pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) {
    connection.query({
      sql: 'INSERT INTO device_data (device_id, timestamp, frequency) VALUES (?, ?, ?);',
      timeout: 40000, 
      values: inserts
    }, function(error, results, fields) {
      connection.release();
      if (error) callback(error);
      else callback(null, results);
    });
  });
};
```

This is the incoming json data

```
"unitID": "arena-MXHGMYzBBP5F6jztnLUdCL",
  "timestamp": 1580915318000,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "frequency": [
    60.0033,
    60.004,
    60.0044,
    60.0032,
    60.005,
    60.005,
    60.0026,
    60.0035,
    60.0036,
    60.0053
  ]
}
```

my frequency has array of values and i am unable to handle that to insert into DB.
Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: i am able to grab one value from frequency array like this 
```
let inserts = [ event.unitID, event.timestamp, event.frequency[0] ];
```

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do. One solution could be creating a table apart for all of the frequencies in your array, then create a relation between that new table and your 'device_data'. Another solution could be mapping all of your readings to have the same device_id, timestamp and only change the frequency.

Comment: @malarres yes i am trying to implement the second solution(mapping all of your readings to have the same device_id, timestamp and only change the frequency)
Any hints ? Thanks

Comment: see my answer below. Where you get your data from? event?

Comment: yes the handler is the method in lambda function that processes events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data is in a variable called json:

```
console.log(json.frequency.map( (freq) =>[json.unitID,json.timestamp,freq] ))
```

you can then tweak this to fit your `sql` to a string that replaces `VALUES (?,?,?)` with your desired output. e.g.:

```
const values = json.frequency.map( (freq) => [json.unitID,json.timestamp,freq] );
const sqlString = `'INSERT INTO device_data (device_id, timestamp, frequency) VALUES ${values.map( (row) => `(${row[0]},${row[1]},${row[2]})` ).join(',')}`
```

and in your code:

```
connection.query({
      sql:sqlString
[...]
```

Comment: I'm not a sql expert but IIRC you could repeat the VALUES part several times https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-multiple-rows/